# Eclipse will not start

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just downloaded Eclipse, unzipped and tried to run but it won't start. The logs are littered with errors such as:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2013-02-01 13:00:36.858
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.200.v20120301-2145 [116]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.extensionlocation; version="0.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-01 13:00:36.874
!MESSAGE Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not start bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.0.v20120522-1841 [88]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment:
```

Given I'm new to Java (coming from .NET) can anyone give me some guidance on how to troubleshoot? The logs are too cryptic for me at this stage.

Comment: seems to be a problem with Eclipse, not Java

Comment: Do you have JRE and JDK installed?

Comment: Java version 1.7.0_11 and JDK 1.4.2.03

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your eclipse zip not contains enough files to start your eclipse application.

What is your eclipse version?

Download:http://www.eclipse.org/downloads

Comment: I downloaded eclipse-SDK-4.2.1-win32 from the main Eclipse site and extracted the contents of the archive from it's root folder.

Comment: Downloaded again and it worked - no idea what was wrong in the previous download. Marking as answer as it prompted me to download it again!

Answer (score 2):

I notice the old installation is now also working. I think the problem might actually have been because I have Oracle installed as well. By removing all of the Oracle Java references from the system variables (Windows XP) seems to have resolved it.

Comment: I have Oracle like you and this solved my problem too.Thanks.